# Spring 3.1 - DefaultMessageListenerContainer - How to identify errors in ErrorHandler

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-jms, xa

Info :: I have a DefaultMessageListener implementation with XA transaction. I have used a MessageListener implementation.

Scenario:: 
My XA transaction is between a DB and a JMS Q Publish. In case of a "data error" in either of them, I need to "move" the source message to a different Q and continue processing rest of the messages.

Problem::
Now, if my DB transaction fails with a DataIntegrity error (primary key violation) then, the XA transaction rolls back at the Container (and not in the MessageListener implementation). So the original message rolls back to the Q, and the message listener gets stuck with this message indefinitely -receiving and failing processing.

How can I check for some exceptions - and handle them differently in the container so that I can continue with the rest of the messages.

ginz

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's the point of an XA transaction - either everything commits or nothing does.

If you want the database transaction to not have any bearing on the Jms transaction, you need

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

on some method upstream of the listener. Catch and handle the exception in the listener and the JMS transaction will commit.

In this scenario (unless there are other resources involved), you really don't need XA - but you do need to handle the (small) possibility of duplicate messages - if the DB transaction commits and the JMS transaction does not, for some reason.

See http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2009/jw-01-spring-transactions.html

Comment: Thanks Gary. But my question is a bit different. I am happy with the "atomicity" of my XA transaction i.e. both (JMS and DB) actions should either happen or not happen. The question is actually - how to differentiate different exceptions and act accordingly - for e.g. I need to perform different actions for DataIntegrity exceptions - and a different one for DB Resource not available aka transient exceptions. As the errors are only raised / captured in the (DefaultMessageListener)Container - I seem to not have control on the exceptions to take different actions. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: Well, you can set the 'norollbackFor' attribute on @Transactional and throw that exception, but you must understand that any DB updates that were successful before the key violation will be committed. A safer solution might be to store a 'bad message' marker (in a new transaction) for the message; then, on delivery, check the JMSRedelivered flag and see if this message is marked as bad in the DB before trying to process it again.